# What does this mean? return func()

Tags: c, function, return

In Linux kernel source code, I found this.

```
int         (*check_fb)(struct device *, struct fb_info *);
...
...
...
static int pwm_backlight_check_fb(struct backlight_device *bl,
                  struct fb_info *info)
{
    struct pwm_bl_data *pb = bl_get_data(bl);

    //something more

    return !pb->check_fb || pb->check_fb(pb->dev, info);
}
```

I don't understand the last `return` statement, what does it mean? And can we return a function? Usually we return a value.

Comment: You should probably learn some basic C. This is pretty basic stuff and it will be quite inefficient to learn by asking a question each time you don't understand something.

Comment: `pb->check_fb(pb->dev, info);` is a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the `||` operator is a short-circuit one, meaning that, if the first argument is true, it never even *evaluates* the second, because `true || anything` is always true.

Hence the statement:

```
return !pb->check_fb || pb->check_fb(pb->dev, info);
```

is a short way of checking for a non-NULL function pointer and using that to decide the current return value:

- If the function pointer is `NULL`, simply return `!NULL`, which will give you `1`.
- If it's *not* NULL, `!pb->check_fb` will evaluate as `0`, so you then have to call the function, and use whatever *it* returns, as the return value of this function.

So it's effectively the same as:

```
if (pb->check_fb == 0)
    return 1;
return pb->check_fb (pb->dev, info);
```

Now I say "effectively" but the actual *values* returned may be slightly different between what you saw, and my final code snippet above. The effect is the same however, if you're treating them as true/false values.

Technically, that final line should be:

```
return 0 || pb->check_fb (pb->dev, info);
```

to have exactly the same return value.

Comment: Just to make it perfect, `which will give you a truth value`...which is `1`, (as per §6.5.3.3, paragraph 5)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not returning  a *function* itself. It is actually

- Checking for non-`NULL` value of the function pointer.

  - If not `NULL`

    1. Calling the function using the function pointer
    2. returning the `return` value of the called function.
  - if `NULL`

    1. return `!NULL` (`1`).

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter 6.8.6.4, *The `return` statement*

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
>   returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression.